# After updating file on google drive through google api, the file on local machine is not editable without closing IDLE window

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I first had a updating problem with using google drive api, Even I followed the example of Quickstart, and after making some changes on it, the file on google drive is updated successfully. But now here comes a new problem after updating, I am not sure if it is because my change to the Quickstart is not proper, or something else. The problem is after updating the an excel file on google drive with an excel file on my local machine, the excel file on my local mahine is not editable if I don't close the IDLE terminal; but if I close the IDLE window, I can do everything with the excel file and save the changes. Such as, without closing the IDLE file, and I made some changes on the excel file and try to save it, then the system says something like sharing violation, and save the file as a temporary file 62635600...., if I try to delete the excel file, then the system says the file is being used by pythonw.exe. After closing the IDLE window, the excel goes back to normal, same as a normal excel file. Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using API v3, I believe the following code will do what you are trying to achieve:

```
def update_file(file_path, fileId):
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype="application/vnd.ms-excel")
    results = file_service.update(fileId=fileId, media_body=media_body).execute()
    return results
```

I am positive about it since I use it in [one of my own applications](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/gDrive-auto-sync) I created to periodically backup files to my Google Drive account.
It also contains some more practical examples to interact with the Google Drive API, in case you are interested.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, I am using v2. Thanks a lot for you help.If I can't make through the v2, I will switch to v3.

Answer (score 1):

You can install google drive on your local machine and copy the file into the google drive directory at the correct position. then google drive (the client software) will update the file.

Comment: hehe, yes I know, but what I need is something to be done automatically instead of manually, that is why I need to write script to do the work. Anyway, thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: yes, do the copy by a script. so write a script, which copies the excel file to the google drive. google drive will detect the change and sync it.

Comment: yes, but how to write the script?  I can write the scrip to insert a file from local drive into google drive, but that is creating a new file in google drive, so if I use the same script everyday , the script will just create multiple new files in google drive instead of replacing the old file with the new file. I know I should use something like service.files().update().excecute() to update a specific file, but how to get the file on local drive, and how to use service.files().update().excecute()  to update a specific file with the local file?

Comment: ok, now I think I know what you mean. I actually need to run this script on a server, the server will do calculation and insert one row number into excel file, and then update the file on google drive with the new generated excel file. The server is on amazon cloud, I am writing the script and testing it on my machine

Comment: There is no Google Drive client software for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example here, and followed it. 
My question is since the "title","descript" and "mimeType" of the local file are exactly same as the file on google drive(cause the local file just has one more row value than the file on google drive, everything else is same), do I need to assign value to these 3 elements? if not, then I can't update the file on google drive with the file on local drive, if I assign value to just "title", the script update the file on google drive with file on local machine, but the weird thing is if I don't close the IDLE terminal, the file on my local machine is not editable, even the phthon script has run successfully and finished, the message I got is something "the file is using by pythonw.exe....", how do I handle this?

```
 def update_file(service, file_id, new_title, new_description, new_mime_type,
                new_filename, new_revision):     
  try:
    file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()

    # File's new metadata.
    file['title'] = new_title
    file['description'] = new_description
    file['mimeType'] = new_mime_type

    # File's new content.
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(
        new_filename, mimetype=new_mime_type, resumable=True)

    # Send the request to the API.
    updated_file = service.files().update(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=file,
        newRevision=new_revision,
        media_body=media_body).execute()
    return updated_file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
    return None
```

Comment: This code is almost correct. So, what is your problem now - not being able to update or file being used by pythonw.exe?

Comment: Also, it would be better to include this in the question itself, rather than writing as an answer.

Comment: I can use this code to update files on google drive. My problem is after I run this script, if I don't close IDLE windowl, then the excel file on my laptop which was updated just now is not editable, and the system says something like this excel file is being used by pythonw.exe; if I close the IDLE window, then the excel file is editable.

Comment: By the way, there is no google drive api for Linux? How do I update files on google drive from a Linux server.

Comment: No, I said that there is no Google Drive Client software for Linux like [the one for Windows](https://www.google.co.in/drive/download/). Consequentially, the only way to interact with Google Drive programmatically would be either use some 3rd-party software or use the Google Drive API and make your own script.

Comment: Regarding the IDLE problem, I can't reproduce it since don't have IDLE on my system. Why don't you instead run it from a terminal directly?

Comment: Also, since you've solved your earlier problem, I suggest you should change the question description accordingly and write about your new problem. That way, you'll get more help.